# How to check if a keystroke was a backspace in the textbox key press event handler

Tags: c#

I am receiving a key press event and want to check if the key in question was a backspace. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT (don't use caps lock or shift)

Comment: What platform? C# isn't specific enough.

Comment: Okay. So, how much are you willing to pay us? We're not doing the work for you, you know. We are mostly here to help you with specific programming related **problems**, not write the code for you. I suggest you start with a C# tutorial book instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back` you need to cast it to `char` since Keys is an enumeration. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mevrick It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Backspace pressed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks vivek again

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".